# Creating your own tokens page content gone

Tags: tokens

Has anyone else noticed the content of this post no longer shows?

https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit

I'm trying to write a token to use the contribution note as a smarty variable but would like to review the tutorial. ..

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, here is some information (and example code) pulled from the blog post.

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens

**Update**: here is a link to the cached  version of the blog post that has the content: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcivicrm.org%2Fblogs%2Fcolemanw%2Fcreate-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcivicrm.org%2Fblogs%2Fcolemanw%2Fcreate-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.7385j0j4&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

The blog post is back and alive:

https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit

Happy coding

Comment: I think somewhere in the life of this blog post the URL was updated. It's now 
https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-for-fun-and-profit (has the word 'for' in the URL now.)